# MongoDB's BSON "_id" looks like scientific notation in Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Occasionally I get a document with an _id value which javascript could and does interpret as scientific notation.

ONLY illustrate the problem I ran the following query.

> db.users.find({$where:'this._id > 1'}).count()

2

There are hundreds of docs in this collection, but those 2 that evaluate as numbers cause problems when they get used in {$in:[]} clauses.

> db.users.findOne({$where:'this._id > 1'})._id

ObjectId("5225141850742e0000002331") - see it's looks like scientific notation right?

I think I run into trouble when I want to store that _id as a string in another collection say as

friendsCollection:
{
_uid:"5225141850742e0000002331"
//more properties here
}

When I retrieve that value, Node (or Mongoose) interprets it as a number like "Infinity".  Then my code ends up trying to search for the user with {_id:{$in:[Infinity]}} which throws an error.

I'm guessing there's a more robust way to store _id values or to handle properties you know to be _ids, but I don't know how.

Comment: how did you define the schema for Users?

Comment: Can I ask why you are using greater than on IDs? Treat them as opaque values and use other fields semantically

Comment: Purely to illustrate that the _id can be evaluated as a number, which causes my problem.  I don't do this in the application.  I updated the text to be more clear about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhh, maybe I should use the Mongoose data type "ObjectId" in my schemas.

For example I was using mongoose schemas like this:

```
locations:{
    _uid:{type:String},//<--probably not good
    lat:{type:Number},
    lng:{type:Number}
},
```

Started using the Schema type "ObjectId":

```
locations:{
    _uid:Schema.Types.ObjectId,//<--better?
    lat: {type:Number},
    lng: {type:Number}
},
```

I have to rebuild a lot of data to support this change.  Also, I won't be sure until another one of those scientific notation _ids pop up, (I deleted the offending docs).  However, this seams promising.

Answer (score 3):

### Converting from hex string to binary representation of ObjectID

If you want to convert from a 24-byte hex string representation of an `_id` value into a binary [ObjectID](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html) as stored in MongoDB, you can use *ObjectID.createFromHexString*:

```
// Need to require ObjectID class if not already included
ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

var uid = ObjectID.createFromHexString("5205c4bd7c21105d0d99648c")
```

### Comparing ObjectIDs

You should be using the [`$gt` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/gt/) for ObjectID comparison rather than [`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/where/).  The `$where` operator evaluates a JavaScript string and cannot take advantage of indexes; it will be much less performant (particularly for this use case).

So the `findOne()` example to find an `_id` greater than a given ObjectID should instead be:

```
db.users.findOne(
    { _id: { $gt: ObjectID("5205c4bd7c21105d0d99648c") } }
)._id
```

For a predictable outcome on finding the next higher ObjectID you should specify an explicit sort order using `find()` with `sort` and `limit`:

```
// Find next _id greater than ObjectID("5205c4bd7c21105d0d99648c") 
db.users.find(
    {_id: { $gt: ObjectID("5205c4bd7c21105d0d99648c") } }
).sort({_id:1}).limit(1).toArray()[0]._id
```

You'll notice that these find examples doesn't explicitly call `createFromHexString`.  The default `ObjectID()` constructor will try to create an appropriate `ObjectID` based on whether the given value is a 24 byte hex string, 12 byte binary string, or a Number.  If you know what sort of value you are providing, it is better to call the expected constructor to limit unexpected conversions (for example if you accidentally provided a Number instead of a hex string).

### Database References (DBRefs)

MongoDB explicitly does not support joins, however there is a convention for storing *database references (DBRefs)* when you want to store the `_id` of a related document as a reference in another document.  Mongoose has a `ref` option that simplifies working with references; see ['Population'](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) in the Mongoose docs.

Comment: In case of `mongoose` `ObjectID = require('mongoose').mongo.ObjectID`. It also automatically converts hex strings to `ObjectID`s, so `{$gt: "5205c4bd7c21105d0d99648c"}` will work the same as `{$gt: ObjectID("5205c4bd7c21105d0d99648c")}`.

Comment: I actually don't want to find _id values greater than a certain value.   I only wrote that query to illustrate an odd result.  Out of thousands of documents, there were actually two _id values that evaluated as a number greater than one.

Comment: @zstew: ObjectIDs are a different [BSON type](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification) from a number, so greater than 1 isn't a useful comparison.  I would expect that the two _id values you returned were actually numeric rather than ObjectIDs?

Answer (score 0):

At some point I had problems when querying _id using the native driver. I fixed it by using ObjectId in my queries. You might find this helpful:

```
var ObjectId = require("mongodb").ObjectID;

query._id = { $gt: ObjectId(idString) }
```